# I wanted to design my loop like this:

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts

I have a loop code which displays posts where the first post has a thumbnail and other posts doesn't contain it. But I want to make it in a specific category.. 
My loop looks like this:

```
    <div class="category">
    <ul>
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php $i = 1 ; ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php if ($i == 1): ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++; endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

So I want to display this by a specific category with the same style..

Comment: can you share more details. does it custom register taxonomy or it is default one? Which category you wish to set over here.

Comment: i will define any cate id there.. i just need the code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your file

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=72&posts_per_page=-1' );  ?>

    <ul>
        <?php 
            while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); 
        ?>
            <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
        <ul>
        <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </ul>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: but i need someone to modify my code..in my code can i just specify the category by pasting this code?

Comment: Just paste my code and change the id 72 instead of yours

Comment: i have a defearant style in mine code..mu loop designs first post with thumbnail  and other 5 posts have not any title..i want that like that..u understand?